# JWT signing with k6

Tags: javascript, jwt, load-testing, k6

How could I encode a JSON object with a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) signature with [k6](https://k6.io/)?

```
export default function() {

  const mySecret = "aaaaaaa";
  const token = jwt.encode({ foo: 'bar' }, mySecret);

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the builtin [k6/encoding](https://docs.k6.io/v1.0/docs/k6encoding) and [k6/crypto](https://docs.k6.io/v1.0/docs/k6cypto) modules to work with JWTs.

Since the `k6/crypto` module doesn't yet support public-key cryptography you can only use shared secrets to sign your JWTs (without doing crypto in pure JS).

Here's an example script:

```
import crypto from "k6/crypto";
import encoding from "k6/encoding";

const algToHash = {
    HS256: "sha256",
    HS384: "sha384",
    HS512: "sha512"
};

function sign(data, hashAlg, secret) {
    let hasher = crypto.createHMAC(hashAlg, secret);
    hasher.update(data);

    // Some manual base64 rawurl encoding as `Hasher.digest(encodingType)`
    // doesn't support that encoding type yet.
    return hasher.digest("base64").replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/=/g, "");
}

function encode(payload, secret, algorithm) {
    algorithm = algorithm || "HS256";
    let header = encoding.b64encode(JSON.stringify({ typ: "JWT", alg: algorithm }), "rawurl");
    payload = encoding.b64encode(JSON.stringify(payload), "rawurl");
    let sig = sign(header + "." + payload, algToHash[algorithm], secret);
    return [header, payload, sig].join(".");
}

function decode(token, secret, algorithm) {
    let parts = token.split('.');
    let header = JSON.parse(encoding.b64decode(parts[0], "rawurl"));
    let payload = JSON.parse(encoding.b64decode(parts[1], "rawurl"));
    algorithm = algorithm || algToHash[header.alg];
    if (sign(parts[0] + "." + parts[1], algorithm, secret) != parts[2]) {
        throw Error("JWT signature verification failed");
    }
    return payload;
}

export default function() {
    let message = { key2: "value2" };
    let token = encode(message, "secret");
    console.log("encoded", token);
    let payload = decode(token, "secret");
    console.log("decoded", JSON.stringify(payload));
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Is there a way to use PS256 algorithm instead of SHA ?

Comment: it is not, based on the documentation [k6/crypto](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-crypto/createhmac/)